# Facebook Android SDK - When using UiLifecycleHelper, should I use Activity or Application for context?

Tags: android, facebook, session

Hi I am currently using Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android.
Here are some facts first.

- Instead of putting my app_id in AndroidManifest.xml, I set that value in my java code programmatically. Hence I use something like the following helper methods when dealing with session.

  ```
  if (session == null || session.isClosed()) {
      String applicationId = Persistent.getString(null, SocialUtil.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
      session = new Session.Builder(Utils.ctx).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
      Session.setActiveSession(session);
  }
  ```
- Once the user logs in with facebook, the session is used in many activities and that's why I provided application context for session.

As you see for the context of session, I provide Utils.ctx which is an Application Object.
Since Facebook SDK's native UiLifecycleHelper creates sesssion with Activity when session doesn't exist, I created my own FBIUiLifecycleHelper by coping the original UiLifeCycleHelper and just switching

```
    session = new Session(activity);
```

to

```
    String applicationId = Persistent.getString(null, SocialUtil.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    session = new Session.Builder(Utils.ctx).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
```

.

However, it seems like whenever Session state changes in my activity, the callback function is NOT called at all. I think it is because I used application context instead of activity context when dealing with session.

MY QUESTION IS,
1. how is it different when you provide application context or activity context for session's context?
2. Which one is a recommened practice when? why?
3. Let's say a user login created a session with activity context. Once this session is set to by setActiveSession(), can this session be used in other activites by calling getActiveSession()? Maybe I don't really have to use application context for session context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. and 2., the Context that you create the Session with does not matter, and can be any Context (app, service, or activity). But when you call any of the open* methods, you must pass in an Activity or a Fragment there via the OpenRequest. If your session is not transitioning between states, then it's an issue there (please post more code around when you're actually opening the session, and make sure you're overriding the onActivityResult method in either your Activity or Fragment).

For 3., yes, you can call getActiveSession from anywhere (Activity, Fragment, or any other code in your app).

Comment: Thanks for enligntening me. Actually The problem I have is that I have a UiLifecycleHalper used in, say Activity A. In A, if the user clicks a button, then activity B is started and starts session opening then activity C opens requesting some publish permission from the user. When C is opened, B calls finish(), and after C is done, C also calls finish() eventually showing the original activity A. In this case, the weird thing is that the moment A's onResume() is called, even though facebook session changed, the callback function of UiLifecycleHelper is not called. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Since the callback function is not called after logging in, now I am just checking the session state in the onPause() of A and perform some stuff when the session is logged-in state. I wanted to use callback function and UiLifecycleHelper but since it doesn't call I am trying to find what's wrong... sigh

Comment: There could be a bug in UiLifecycleHelper when you do session management across multiple activities. Are you using the same active session (but just requesting new permissions)?

Comment: Yes that's true. Whenever I request new permissions, I always get the existing session by calling Session.getActiveSession()

Comment: If you get a reliable repro case, you can always report it as a bug here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs